# Is there a website which shows indexes and their corresponding ETFs?

Tags: etf, websites

I am looking for a website which shows a list of indexes and their corresponding ETFs. Specifically, I'm looking for a list where the first column lists indexes from around the world and the second column lists one or several ETFs which track that specific index.

Does anyone know of a site with such an easy overview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest you're going to come to this is an ETF database like [this one](http://etfdb.com/etfs/). I haven't used this site before, but it looks like you can browse ETF's by category and find relevant information for them. For example, you can browse the list of [ETF's that track agricultural commodities](http://etfdb.com/etfdb-category/agricultural-commodities/) and navigate to specific funds.

I wasn't able to find any site with the highly specific format that you're looking for, but if you're merely using this for research, the site I found should be acceptable. If your goal is parsing such information, you'll need to explore further.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for, but it will have to do ;-). I must, admit I came across this site myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another webpage on (multitudinous) ETF databases but I'm unsure whether this is your goal: http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424127887324590904578291921490378796. In summary:

1. Morningstar.com
2. ETFdb.com
3. IndexUniverse.com
4. XTF.com
5. ETF-Company Sites :

   > When researching a single fund or a group of ETFs within the same family, investors should go right to the source, suggests Jerry Slusiewicz, an adviser in Laguna Hills, Calif. He points out that sites from fund companies such as Vanguard Group, BlackRock Inc. BLK +2.07% 's iShares unit and State Street Corp.'s STT -0.68% State Street Global Advisors often provide the best-scrubbed summaries of basic portfolio data.